# Ubuntu 18.04 is broken once I use a static IP

Tags: networking, 18.04, ethernet, ip, static-ip

When I try to change my wired ethernet connection from DHCP to Manaul, with the IP `192.168.100.100` and the Netmask of 24 and a gateway of `192.168.121.1`, the connection suddenly stops working. Could someone help me fix this?
I am using the DNS of '8.8.8.8'.

I am using Ubuntu Desktop. I am using `Ubuntu 18.04.04 LTS`.

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: What are the corresponding numbers when you use DHCP? I suspect that the gateway and the IP address are both in 192.168.100.xx. Also, you have not specified DNS nameservers.

Comment: 192.168.100.100 is not in the same subnet as 192.168.121.1.  You would have to put your static IP in the same subnet for that to work.  192.168.121.100 would be in the same subnet.

Answer (score 0):

Your gateway has to be in same subnet as your IP is.

For example:

IP 192.168.100.100

GW: 192.168.100.1 or whatever it is.

Netmask is your netmask.

IN /24 netmask your gateway can be only in 192.168.100.1 - 192.168.0.100.254 range. By default it's 192.168.100.1 or 192.168.100.254

Or if you don't know your IP but you know your gateway, then you can configure like that:

IP: 192.168.121.252

Netmask: 255.255.255.0

Gateway: 192.168.121.1

DNS: 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4 (or another public DNS)

Comment: So if I type in the last couple IP, Netmask, Gateway, and DNS, my static IP should work?

Comment: We don’t know. Is your network in 192.168.100.1 or is it in 192.168,121.1? That’s why I asked about the numbers if you select DHCP.